# Registering a script at the end of the page using RegisterClientScriptBlock to avoid sys undefined error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I need to call the following programatically to set something up when a modal popup is shown.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(modalSetup);
```

Something along the lines.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            Sys.Application.add_load(modalSetup);
            function modalSetup() {
                var modalPopup = $find("PopupBehaviorId");
                if (modalPopup != null) {
                    modalPopup.add_shown(SetFocusOnControl);
                }
            }

            function SetFocusOnControl() {
                alert('test');
            }
        </script>
```

Now the problem is that I have a `script manager` on the master page.

If I put this script manually (not programatically) below the `script manager in the master page`, it will work correctly.

But when I'm adding this programatically in the user control for modal popup (which I need to) using either `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock or Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, it throws the famous `sys is undefined` error.

I know this is happening because this programatic injection puts it into the `Head section` before the `ScriptManager` line is executed.

How can I get around this. Is it possible to say insert this script at the end of the page and not at the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ScriptManager's RegisterStartupScript method.

Comment: So, I have been struggling for the last two days trying to figure out why one of my startup scripts did not work.  I had one on the page already, that worked fine.  But I added a second (incidentally, to open a modal popup after populating it with data from the server), and this one would not work.  Somehow, on the second one I typed RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of RegisterStartupScript.  I love Intellisense, but sometimes ....  So a one line answer would have saved me two days, if I had bothered to search.  I am putting a bounty on this question just to say thank you for this.